# Jquery autocomplete, right JSON Data but text field is empty

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

i have a problem with an jquery autocomplete. i have an external data-source (PHP). The returned JSON-Data looks right  [{"value":"Schubert Till","label":"Schubert Till"}], but nothing is shown in the text input box, advices? It has worked before, then i have switched to a responsive design template... but i doubt, that this is somehow connected. Please help.

HTML part:

```
    <input type="text" id="p4" name="p4" value="" />
```

external JavaScript:

```
 $( "#p4" ).autocomplete({
          source: "autocompletePartner.php",
          minLength: 2,
          select: function( a, b ) {
            $(this).val(b.item.value);
          }
      });
```

PHP last Part:

```
while($zeile=$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
    $player_id = $zeile[0];
    $lastname = $zeile[2];
    $firstname = $zeile[1];

    $a_json_row[value] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
    $a_json_row[label] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;

    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
  }
echo json_encode($a_json);
mylog (json_encode($a_json));
flush();
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in console? Maybe you could try `$("#p4").val` instead of `$(this).val`

Comment: Are you using `autocomplete` from jQuery UI or some other autocomplete plugin ? Do you see any errors in console ?

Comment: Also it would help if you can post the sample JSON response you receive from PHP

Comment: Assuming you're using jQuery UI's autocomplete, then `select` is a callback invoked when the user selects some value in your suggestions list. If you need a callback to deal with Server response from `autocompletePartner.php`, then I suggest you use the function variant of `source`

Comment: no errors in the console. I am using autocomplete from jQueryUI. I don't even get a sugegstion list displayed in the text input field, so I think the problem is not selecting one, the problem is the display

Comment: open your firebug and watch changes in the DOM below your input. I'm sure it's a CSS problem. jQuery manipulates but you can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure your input element is having **autocomplete="off"**

```
<input type='text' class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" id="autocomplete" />
```

Then use Jquery as **Arkantos**  suggested above comment.